# What specs for binoculars to spot climbing routes?

Tags: rock-climbing, binoculars

What `Z x W` would you recommend for spotting a rock climbing route (up to about 30,40 meters high - standing in front of it)? Checking for cracks f.x., to estimate what cams you need to take with you and if bolts look safe.

`Z` in `{8,10}` and `W` in `[25mm,50mm]`.

8x25 would be more stable, little less zoom, less bright and less weight

while

10x50 would be less stable, little more zoom, brighter and more weight.

Comment: I'm no climber but I've had a few pairs of binoculars. Assuming you're climbing in decent weather you don't need anything x50 (or even x42 unless the rock is *very* dark or you're looking into deep shade). 10x25 to 10x30 might be quite nice - you'll get good detail at that range. I've seen 10x25 *mon*oculars which could save you some weight/bulk. Most monocs are more like 8x20.

Comment: What kind of height of climb are we talking here? single pitch, multi pitch?

Answer (score 3):

In binocular I would say 8x25 for size and weight.  I don't think you want weight or bulk of a 10x but if you are driving to the face then weight is not an issue.  You can find some light 10x but for me at a 10x I like a longer binocular.

Field of view is not important in spotting a route.  For weight (and volume) I would go with [monocular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocular) but then ironically would go 10x.  You don't have the weight issue.  A longer 10x is physically easier to handle.  You get higher quality lenses for the same money.  For me a monocular is easier to stabilize as it is lighter and you can use two hands - I also shoot pistol.  Take it up the route with you for site seeing at the top.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43985/discussion-on-answer-by-paparazzi-what-specs-for-binoculars-to-spot-climbing-rou).